# Using JNR-FFI to output a char table to CMD screen buffer crashes

Tags: java, c++, winapi, cmd

I'm trying to write a library in Java that'll use C++ code to access an write directly to console screen buffer in CMD. I've managed to print out one time, but it crashes after that with exit code `0xC0000005`

I used JNR-FFI library. This code now prints out the first frame of animation, pauses on if for a second and crashes.

Here's that code:

```
import jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader;
import jnr.ffi.Pointer;

public class Main {

    public interface Kernel32 {
        Kernel32 INSTANCE = LibraryLoader.create(Kernel32.class).load("kernel32");

        int GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        int GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
        int FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001;
        int FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002;
        int CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER = 1;

        Pointer CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(int dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode, Pointer lpSecurityAttributes, int dwFlags, Pointer lpScreenBufferData);
        void SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(Pointer hConsoleOutput);
        int WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(Pointer hConsoleOutput, char[] lpCharacter, int nLength, int dwWriteCoord, int lpNumberOfCharsWritten);
    }

    private static final int nScreenWidth = 240;
    private static final int nScreenHeight = 135;

    static Kernel32 kernel32 = Kernel32.INSTANCE;

    private static Pointer hConsole = kernel32.CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
            Kernel32.GENERIC_WRITE | Kernel32.GENERIC_READ,
            Kernel32.FILE_SHARE_READ | Kernel32.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            null,
            Kernel32.CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
            null
    );

    public static void writeCMD(char[] screen){
        try {
            if (screen.length == (nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight) + 1) {
                int lpNumberOfCharsWritten = 0;
                System.out.println(kernel32.WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hConsole, screen, (nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight) + 1, 0, lpNumberOfCharsWritten));
            }
        } catch (Exception t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        kernel32.SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);

        char[] screen = new char[(nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight) + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < screen.length - 1; i++) {
            screen[i] = '-';
        }
        screen[screen.length - 1] = '\0';

        int position = 0;
        while(true){
            screen[position] = '#';
            writeCMD(screen);
            screen[position] = '-';
            position++;
        }
    }
}
```

Running it in CMD as mentioned prints the first frame, freezes on that for a sec and crashes with no exception, but running it in IntelliJ console gave me exit code `0xc0000005' and found this in event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: java.exe, version: 20.0.2.0, time stamp: 0x75f7bb13
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.22621.2715, time stamp: 0x10f6a783
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000b5bdc
Faulting process id: 0x0x5B98
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DA1CB1377C8871
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\java.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 97a532d2-82fd-4b33-a399-ee74ea9e606d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Tried googling it but didn't find anything I made sense of. Any help?

Comment: 0xC0000005 is access violation. Somebody used a resource they don't own. Usually this is marching outside an array or using an uninitialized or dangling pointer, but just about anything could trigger it.

Comment: You'll have to examine the complete OS stack dump (not the Java stack trace) to see where in the JNR-FFI library the error occurred.  Could be you passed an incorrect parameter somewhere, or there's a bug in the library.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody pointed out that the last parameter in `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW()` should have been a Pointer to a long var instead of an int.

---

Changing this:
`int lpNumberOfCharsWritten = 0;` in 'WroteCMD()'

---

to this:
`Pointer lpNumberOfCharsWritten = Runtime.getSystemRuntime().getMemoryManager().allocate( Runtime.getSystemRuntime().findType( TypeAlias.int32_t ).size() );`

---

fixed the issue. I was using an int as a memory address and this was trying to write to, in this case, address 0.